# TS: class private property undefined in protected function

Tags: typescript

why class private property undefined in protected function?

I have the following class hierarchy in a Typescript project:

route.base.ts:

```
export abstract class RouteBase {
  public router = Router()

  constructor() {
    this.init()
  }

  protected init(): void {
    this.registerRoute()
  }

  protected abstract registerRoute(): void
}
```

app.routing.ts:

```
export class AppRoute extends RouteBase {
  private apiRoute = new ApiRoute()

  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  protected registerRoute(): void {
    this.router.use('/api', this.apiRoute.router)
  }
}
```

api.routing.ts:

```
export class ApiRoute extends RouteBase {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }

  protected registerRoute(): void {
    this.router.get('/test', (req, res, next) => res.send('api test.'))
  }
}
```

I declare 'appRoute':
`const appRoute = new AppRoute()`
then I got a error message:

```
    this.router.use('/api', this.apiRoute.router)
                                          ^
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'router')
```

I think RouteBase#constructor is invoked first, which call build when this.apiRoute is not yet set.
So what would be the recommended practise here?

Comment: Post the last relevant stack entries here too. I suspect it's an initialisation order problem. The stack should tell you.